# Manter sessão com AngularJs Authentication

Tags: angularjs, session, autenticação

Estou usando o esse [projeto](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/angularjs-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) para fazer autenticação com AngularJS.

Estou usando o AngularJS 1.6.4 com WildFly 10 com Java 8 e SQL Server 2014. Eu consigo fazer o login corretamente, mas quando eu atualizo a página a sessão não é mantida.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Além das adaptações de 'rest' que tenho que fazer em 'user.servi.js' (aqui está o [arquivo original](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example/blob/master/app-services/user.service.js)), tenho que fazer o que para conseguir manter a sessão?

Aqui está o meu código user.service.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('UserService', UserService);

    UserService.$inject = ['$http'];
    function UserService($http) {
        var service = {};

        //service.GetAll = GetAll;
        //service.GetById = GetById;
        service.GetByUsername = GetByUsername;
        service.Create = Create;
        //service.Update = Update;
        //service.Delete = Delete;

        return service;

        //function GetAll() {
        //    return $http.get('rest/usuarios/login/').then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting all users'));
        //}

        //function GetById(id) {
        //    return $http.get('rest/usuarios/login/' + id).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting user by id'));
        //}

        function GetByUsername(usermatricula, usersenha) {
            return $http.post('rest/usuarios/login/' + usermatricula + '/' + usersenha).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting user by username'));
        }

        function Create(user) {
            return $http.post('rest/usuarios/', user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
        }

        //function Update(user) {
        //    return $http.put('rest/usuarios/login/' + user.id, user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error updating user'));
        //}

        //function Delete(id) {
        //    return $http.delete('rest/usuarios/login/' + id).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error deleting user'));
        //}

        // private functions

        function handleSuccess(res) {
            console.log(res.data);
            return res.data;
        }

        function handleError(error) {
            return function () {
                return { success: false, message: error };
            };
        }
    }

})();
```

Já tentei de tudo, ou quase tudo. Já aviso que sou novo em AngularJS, HTML5, JavaScript, Java...

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Ainda não!! Já tentei muitas coisas, mas até agora nada!! Tem alguma coisa em mente que eu possa tentar?

Comment: Eu experimentei o projeto dele com node, e funcionou, aparentemente - você já fez esse teste?

Comment: Eu testei usando o arquivo [user.service.local-storage.js](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example/blob/master/app-services/user.service.local-storage.js), que seria para um Fake User Service e funciona, mas para um servidor real o mesmo recomenda o [user.service.js](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example/blob/master/app-services/user.service.js), e comigo não etá funcionando. Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: Sim - eu estou me referindo **antes** disso - eu apenas baixei o projeto, e usei o servidor [tag:nodejs] como descrito [aqui](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/06/22/nodejs-setup-simple-http-server-local-web-server) - sugiro que você faça isso e teste. Eu testei com o código que você postou acima, e funcionou também, então o problema está em outro lugar, e vai ser difícil a comunidade te ajudar sem as informações que faltam. Se for um problema no WildFly, a pergunta terá que ser reescrita. Teste e nos avise... ;)

Comment: Quando testei o projeto usei o [live-server](https://basementmedia.no/2015/06/26/previewing-website-when-editing-in-visual-studio-code/). Acho que é a mesma coisa, não? No seu teste, você chegou a buscar o usuário pelo banco?(Se sim, o http-server consegue conectar direto banco? No meu caso o SQL Server?) E como posso saber se o problema é o Wildfly? :) Deixe me saber qual outra parte do código você quer que eu poste.

Comment: Não cheguei a usar banco de dados - mas você pretende manter sessão por SQL também? Eu sugiro que você teste isoladamente cada coisa - mova o projeto *que funciona* para o WildFly, e veja se ele continua funcionando, feito isso, inclua o SQL. O http-server parece apenas servir páginas estáticas e mais nada.

Comment: "manter sessão por SQL também", fique na duvida agora, como assim?  Fiquei interessado sobre o assunto. - Vou isolar o projeto, talvez seja melhor fazer uma copia. - Então o que você recomenda, manter sessão pelo AngularJS ou de outra maneira? E como seria essa outra maneira. PS: Não queria usar 'php', só para deixar claro.